# Php - split specific word by explode in string

Tags: php, split, explode

I want to split words from string. for example, my string is "In the #name of god" and i need the "name" only!!
but when i use this snipet, return me "name of god"

```
$string = "In the #name of god";    
$word   = explode( '#', $string );
echo $word;
```

Comment: `$word` is array, when you echo it you won't see `name of god`

Comment: you are using export here in wrong context. The `explode()` function breaks a string into an array.

Comment: @u_mulder, Array ( [0] => In the [1] => name of god )

Comment: I suggest using a regex function to match on the regular expression `#\w+` where `\w` matches "word" characters (`a-z`, `0-9`, and `_`). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = "In the #name of god";

// Using `explode`
$word   = @reset(explode(' ', end(explode( '#', $string ))));
echo $word; // 'name'

// Using `substr`
$pos1 = strpos($string, '#');
$pos2 = strpos($string, ' ', $pos1) - $pos1;
echo substr($string, $pos1 + 1, $pos2);  // 'name'
```

> Note: The `@` character before the `reset` function is an [**Error Control Operators**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). It avoid to display a warning message when using `end` function with a non-reference variable, and yes, it's a bad practice. You should create your own variable and pass to `end` function. Like this:

```
// Using `explode`
$segments = explode( '#', $string );
$segments = explode(' ', end($segments));
$word = reset($segments);
echo $word; // 'name'
```

Answer (score 1):

try regex and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$string = "In the #name of god";
preg_match('/(?<=#)\w+/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => name )
```

Comment: This also returns an array? a string was requested in the question

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, but `$matches[0]` will have required string and the complexity is very less in this.

Comment: also would suggest to use `preg_match_all` to get all the occurances

Comment: @knets yes that's true

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

*Sorry, I just readed it wrong.*

[Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) converts an String into Array.
So your output'll result in ["In the ", "name of god"]. If you want to catch an word on it you need to be more specific on how it'll work. If you just want to catch the first word after a hashtag you should use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
$string = "In the #name of god";
$hashtag_pos = strpos($string, "#");
if($hashtag_pos === false)
    echo ""; // hashtag not found
else {
    $last_whitespace_after_hashtag = strpos($string, " ", $hashtag_pos);
    $len = $last_whitespace_after_hashtag === false ? strlen($string)-($hashtag_pos+1) : $last_whitespace_after_hashtag - ($hashtag_pos+1);
    echo substr($string, $hashtag_pos+1, strpos($string, " ", $len));
}
```

Comment: This definitely not returns `name`

Comment: @Daan Fixed it.

Comment: None of my business but returns `#name` rather than `name`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options (also preg_match would help for multiple instances of '#')

```
<?php
//With Explode only (meh)
$sen = "In the #name of god";
$w = explode(' ', explode('#',$sen)[1])[0];

echo $w;

//With substr and strpos
$s = strpos($sen , '#')+1; // find where # is
$e = strpos(substr($sen, $s), ' ')+1; //find i
$w = substr($sen, $s, $e);

echo $w;

//with substr, strpos and explode
$w = explode(' ', substr($sen, strpos($sen , '#')+1))[0];
echo $w;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my own project, I would certainly avoid making a handful of function calls to replicate what can be done with one `preg_` function call.

Effectively, match the literal `#`, then "forget" it with `\K`, then match one or more non-whitespace characters.  The fullstring match is accessed by index `0` if there is a match in the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cRFcR))

```
$string = "In the #name of god";

echo preg_match('~#\K\S+~', $string, $match) ? $match[0] : '';
// output: name
```